# Firefox Addons SDK: background job or process

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to load and execute a specific script with a time interval in background?

**Update**

Say, user defined a time interval like 5min. With this time interval an addons will clear browser cache. So, to implement this didn't we need a background job?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to load and execute a specific script with a time interval in background?

What do you mean by a time interval? and what do you mean by background?

My blind guess is that a [page-worker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html) will work tho.